# Android: how to combine Activity.onTouchEvent() and View.setOnLongClickListener() capabilities

Tags: android, event-handling

In Android, I'm trying to capture user touches as well as User long-touches.  I have an Activity and in it I override the `onTouchEvent()` method to handle a variety of screen touches.

I'm trying to incorporate "Long Presses" into my repertoire of User Interface choices.

I can't find a `Activity.onLongTouchEvent()` for me to override.

My application also has a SurfaceView and I see that I can do this:

```
sv.setOnLongClickListener (new View.OnLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick (View v)
    {
        SendAToast();
        return false;
    }
});
```

When I implement that code, it works exactly like it should.

However, now my `onTouchEvent()` code is never called even when I don't touch the screen long enough for it to be a "Long Press".

Is anybody aware of a way to get these two bits of code to work together?

Edit:

After I posted this, a co-worker showed me the "OnGestureListener" interface.  Here's an example:

http://www.ceveni.com/2009/08/android-gestures-detection-sample-code.html

I use the interface to capture long presses, and it even provides the screen coordinates to work with (which the OnLongClickListener does not).  So, it seems to do the trick.

Why this function not automatically part of the Activity?  It sure seems like core functionality to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the on touch stuff into the view's onTouchEvent instead of the Activity.

Comment: That's probably something I should've thought about at the very beginning, but I had no idea it even existed.  Now, I'm thinking there's too much code, to close to release to undertake that.  I'll definitely keep that idea in mind when we move to version 2.